# D3.js Time series graph with epoch time

Tags: d3.js, time, charts

I have data captured every 5 minutes, data would be in pairs of a unix epoch timestamp and a value. I would like to render a bar chart with this data. Can this be easily accomplished in D3.js or is there a better tool for the job? Any examples? Ideally I'd like to have it refresh as additional data points come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe EpochJS is worth looking at? They have examples on their website of different realtime charts...

http://epochjs.github.io/epoch/

Comment: Thanks- I think that's exactly what I was looking for- I didn't run across that when I was searching.